# Brownian motion with Karhunen-Loéve expansion

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, monte-carlo, simulation

I try to simulate Brownian motion using Karhunen-Loéve expansion in R. I found that formula is:

$$W_t=\sqrt2\sum_{k \ge0} \gamma_k\frac{2}{(2k+1)\pi}\sin\bigg(\bigg(k+\frac{1}{2}\bigg)\pi t\bigg)$$

I tried this code:

```
n<-1000
T. <- 1
delta <-T./n
k<- c(1:1000)
W_kl <- matrix(NA, ncol = 10, nrow = n)
for (i in 1:10){

  summands <- rnorm(n, 0, 1) * (2 / (2*k +1) * pi) * sin((k + 1/2) * pi * delta)
  W_kl[,i] <- sqrt(2) * cumsum(summands)
}
matplot(W_kl, type = "l")
```

The beginning of the graph looks fine, but endings no, I got this:
[image]

By using another method which is really correct I got such a graph:
[image]

Maybe somebody can say what is wrong with my code?

Comment: The problem is that you are taking n aas the time but it's not it's the number of gaussians, if you want to plot with time you have to make your function a function of time through parameter delta and run delta through multiple values (1 to 1000 to be coherent with your second plot). In KL series you sample your gaussians once and for all time it's not like sampling a brownian path with normal increments.

Comment: @TheBridge Actually before delta I used simply T, but got even worse results. I'm actually very new in this field and R, so will really appreciate it if you will help me with code above updating.